# автоматическая инициализация зубчатого массива

Tags: c#

не прошу весь код, просто подскажите, наведите на мысль... стоит задача: пользователь вводит произвольное число элементов массивов. программа создает массив из строк по 10 элементов. естественно, число может быть не кратным 10, поэтому последняя строка может быть меньше чем 10 элементов. имеем зубчатый массив, который должен быть заполнен рандомными числами. как автоматизировать инициализацию массивов массива? допустим, пользователь ввел 99 элементов. программа рассчитывает 9 строк по 10 элементов и десятая строка из девяти элементов. предполагаемая наброска кода ниже:

```
public static void Main (string[] args)
{
    int[][] myArr = new int[8][];
    for(int i=0; i<8; i++)
    {
        myArr[i] = new int[10];
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
    {
        myArr[i][j] = j;
        Console.Write("{0}\t", myArr[i][j]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Перефразируйте ваш вопрос, непонятно что вам надо и что вы делаете. Ваш код даже компилироваться не будет

Comment: это и не код. это так, мысли вслух. спрашиваем у пользователя количество элементов массива. программа вводит строки по 10 элементов в каждой строке. но, если пользователь, допустим ввел не 100, а 99? 9 элементов будут будут в десятой строке. получается у нас зубчатый массив. везде приводится пример ручной инициализации каждой строки зубчатого массива. Как сделать, чтобы программа автоматически создавала строки зубчатого массива по 10, а в последнюю строку количество элементов как остаток деления введенного числа на 10. Это вообще возможно? и если да, то как?

Comment: само условие задачи тривиально. ввести число элементов массива, автоматически создать массив из строк по 10 элементов, заполнить рандомными числами. может я просто все усложняю и сделать так, чтобы при расчете количества строк просто округлялось до нуля в десятке?

Comment: если все усложняю, то прямоугольный массив сделаю сам. с подсказками можете в этом случае не утруждаться. Спасибо за внимание

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Простое решение задачи через div-rem:

```
[ThreadStatic]
static readonly Random rand = new Random();

int[][] CreateArray(int itemCount)
{
    const int fullRowLen = 10;

    // checks skipped

    var fullRowCount = itemCount / fullRowLen; // кол-во "полных" строк
    var additionalRowLen = itemCount % fullRowLen; // длина последней строки

    int[][] arr;

    if (additionRowLen == 0) // кратно 10
    {
        arr = new int[fullRowCount][];

        for (var i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
            arr[i] = new int[fullRowLen];
    }
    else
    {
        arr = new int[fullRowCount + 1][];

        for (var i = 0; i < arr.Length - 1; i++)
            arr[i] = new int[fullRowLen];

        arr[^1] = new int[additionalRowLen];
    }

    foreach (var subarr in arr)
        for (var i = 0; i < subarr.Length; i++)
            subarr[i] = rand.Next();

    return arr;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Долго думал, но кажется понял задачу, вот решение:

```csharp
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int[][] myArray = new int[10][];
    Random rndGenerator = new Random();
    int count;

    Console.Write("Введите число элементов массива: ");
    while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out count) || count <= 0)
    {
        Console.Write("Неверный ввод, попробуйте еще раз: ");
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < myArray.Length; i++)
    {
        myArray[i] = new int[i < myArray.Length - 1 ? 10 : count % 10];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < myArray.Length; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < myArray[i].Length; j++)
        {
            myArray[i][j] = rndGenerator.Next(-30, 45);
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < myArray.Length; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < myArray[i].Length; j++)
        {
            Console.Write(myArray[i][j].ToString().PadLeft(3, ' '));
            if (j < myArray[i].Length - 1)
                Console.Write(", ");
            else
                Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Вывод в консоль

```
Введите число элементов массива: 93
 -1,  21,  14, -29, -14,  -1, -22,  30, -27, -22
-22,  22,  32,  12, -24,  19, -16,  41,  23,  -4
-10, -23,  -2, -29, -23,  11,  -7,  38,  23,  18
-13,  -3, -10,  11,  20,  35,   5,   7,  -2,  -6
-30,  43,  16,  -4,  -8,  28,  32,  24,  12,  -6
 21,   1,   7,  -9, -18,  -8,  -7,  12,  39,  20
-24, -15, -23,   0,  36,  26,   2, -10,  37, -15
-17,  22,  13,  -1,  -5,  -9,   5, -29,  23,  -7
 23,  14,  -5,  -2,  42,  30,  34,  43,  -1,  -3
 11,  38,  13
```

Comment: за подсказку спасибо. но это немного не то. то, что привели вполне понятно.

Comment: 1. Написать программу, которая запрашивает число элементов массива, после чего создает массив, заполняет его случайными целыми числами в диапазоне от  -30 до 45 и выводит на экран строками по 10 элементов. Программа должна после этого вывести элементы массива в обратном направлении, начиная с последнего, игнорируя отрицательные элементы.

Comment: мне непонятно как быть, если пользователь введет число элементов массива, которое не делится на 10. и если так, то мы должны создать зубчатый массив? а как его создать автоматически, а не в ручную забивать строки?

Comment: Я вроде-как давно обновил код.

Comment: спасибо за помощь

Comment: @АртемБондаренко но в вашей задаче ничего не сказано про "зубчатый" массив, там просто типа массив.

Comment: стоило бы добавить alignment для вывода, а то глаза режет

Comment: @return так не режет?)

Comment: @aepot нет, уже не режет)